# MAPI/HTTP connectivity issue on Exchange 2016

Tags: exchange-2016

In my production environment, there is one exchange 2016 mailbox server and MAPI already enabled on it. Most of users have Microsoft office 2010 and some has office 2016. Now all of Microsoft office 2010 users don't have any issue on outlook connectivity to exchange but outlook 2016 users experiencing with MAPI/HTTP connectivity issue to exchange.

I checked following MAPI test command on my exchange server and result is success.

```
Test-OutlookConnectivity -RunFromServerId ContosoMail -ProbeIdentity OutlookMapiHttpSelfTestProbe
```

and I checked connection status of outlook 2016.

Answer (score 2):

Does the issue have an influence on all Outlook 2016 clients or certain ones?
Could you provide the error information snapshot?

The MAPI/HTTP connections are designated in the Protocol column using the string HTTP. Please check if Outlook 2016 clients show correctly.

[image]

1. By default, outlook 2016 could connect to Exchange 2016 using MAPI over HTTPS after Exchange has been installed and without any configurations. We could run the following command to check SCP:
   Get-ClientAccessService | FL *inter*
2. Please delete all outlook profile on Windows client and create outlook profile manually, then check if we could start outlook.
3. Please check if there are any related event id in application log on Exchange server and post them for our troubleshooting.

When a proxy is enabled that has your own domain listed as an exception, Outlook cannot connect to the Exchange Server by using MAPI over HTTP. More detailds you could refer to the following thread.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/37739c13-8aeb-45ba-b157-f47518b3e15f/exchange-server-2016-cu5-mapihttp-outlook-authn-error-kerberos-ntlm?forum=Exch2016CM